# Cannot plot a 2d surface with surface countours using matplotlib

Tags: arrays, matplotlib

I would like to plot a multivariate function f_ab using the `axes3d` method with a and b as "variables". For some reason, the method throws an error saying that z is not a 2d array. If I check the shape of f_ab, I get (50,50)

```
import numpy as np

a = np.linspace(5,10,50)
b = np.linspace(3,8,50)

f_ab = np.zeros((len(a),len(b)))

for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(b)):
        f_ab[i,j] = (a[i]**0.5)*(b[j])
        
        
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(projection='3d')
X, Y, Z = a, b, f_ab

# Plot the 3D surface
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, edgecolor='royalblue', lw=0.5, rstride=8, cstride=8,
                alpha=0.3)

# Plot projections of the contours for each dimension.  By choosing offsets
# that match the appropriate axes limits, the projected contours will sit on
# the 'walls' of the graph.
ax.contour(X, Y, Z, zdir='z', offset=np.min(f_ab), cmap='coolwarm')
ax.contour(X, Y, Z, zdir='x', offset=50, cmap='coolwarm')
ax.contour(X, Y, Z, zdir='y', offset=50, cmap='coolwarm')

ax.set(xlim=(0,50), ylim=(0,50), zlim=(np.min(f_ab),np.max(f_ab)),
       xlabel='a', ylabel='b', zlabel='z')
```

The error looks like this:

```
File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py:1501, in QuadContourSet._check_xyz(self, args, kwargs)
   1498 z = ma.asarray(args[2], dtype=np.float64)
   1500 if z.ndim != 2:
-> 1501     raise TypeError(f"Input z must be 2D, not {z.ndim}D")
   1502 if z.shape[0] < 2 or z.shape[1] < 2:
   1503     raise TypeError(f"Input z must be at least a (2, 2) shaped array, "
   1504                     f"but has shape {z.shape}")

TypeError: Input z must be 2D, not 1D
```

I tried changing the zdir parameter in the ax.contour, but could not get the desired result.

How can I resolve the error?

Comment: `ax.contour(X, Y, Z, zdir='x')` wants `X` to be 2D.  You could try `X, Y = np.meshgrid(a, b)` together with `Z = f_ab`.  That way, all 3 are 2D.